# SQL query - get rows from a table based on one condition and through join table based on another condition

Tags: sql

I have a tags table - id, name, owner_id (owner_id is FK for users)

and a user_tags table - user_id, tag_id (linking table between users a tags for the purpose of sharing those tags - ie, users who can access the tag but aren't the owner)

I have a query that can get me tags through a join on the user_tags table:

```
SELECT tags . * 
FROM tags
JOIN user_tags ON user_tags.user_id =2
AND user_tags.tag_id = tags.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But in that same query I'd also like to select tags WHERE tags.owner_id = 2, getting all tags shared with that user through the linking table(user_tags) and also tags that user owns (tags.owner_id = user_id).

If I include WHERE tags.owner_id = 2 after the join, It only returns results where tags.owner_id = 2.

If I include OR tags.owner_id = 2, I get repeats of all the results.

If I make the statement `SELECT DISTINCT... OR tags.owner_id = 2` I end up with the correct result set, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do this join with condition.

Is there a better way/best practice?

Also, why does a join return multiples of the results (ie why is `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` necessary?

Thank you.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION OF STRUCTURE**

Comment: Can you add the DDL for your tables?  I'm pretty sure user_tags is a bridge table.  Is tags.owner_id a foreign key?  It would be helpful to know the relationships of your data a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use user_tags.user_id as part of the join condition.  Just do specify both conditions in the where clause to make your intent clearer.  But to answer your question, yes you would need to de-dupe tags with DISTINCT if one tags.id can be associated to many user_tags.tag_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.*
FROM tags
JOIN user_tags ON tags.id = user_tags.tag_id
WHERE user_tags.user_id = 2
OR user_tags.owner_id = 2
LIMIT 0,30
```